# Spacing in a string

Tags: android, string, formatting, character

What is the character to use to Place a 'return' in a string resource?

IE:  In the value of a string, '/' means there is no space before the words in the string....Is there a char to use that puts in a return so I can have the string displayed in multiple paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\n` or if it's going to output to HTML, `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by '/', but would a \n (newline character) work?